# Golang Goroutine synchronization with channel

Tags: go

I have the following program where the HTTP server is created using gorilla mux.
When any request comes, it starts goroutine 1. In processing, I am starting another goroutine 2.
I want to wait for goroutine 2's response in goroutine 1? How I can do that?
How to ensure that only goroutine 2 will give the response to goroutine 1?

There can be GR4 created by GR3 and GR 3 should wait for GR4 only.

GR = Goroutine

[image]

**SERVER**

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Post struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Body  string `json:"body"`
}

var posts []Post

var i = 0

func getPosts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    i++
    fmt.Println(i)
    ch := make(chan int)
    go getTitle(ch, i)

    p := Post{
        ID: "123",
    }
    // Wait for getTitle result and update variable P with title

    s := <-ch
    //

    p.Title = strconv.Itoa(s) + strconv.Itoa(i)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(p)
}

func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    posts = append(posts, Post{ID: "1", Title: "My first post", Body: "This is the content of my first post"})
    router.HandleFunc("/posts", getPosts).Methods("GET")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9999", router)
}

func getTitle(resultCh chan int, m int) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    resultCh <- m
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "io/ioutil"
    "time"
)


func main(){

for i :=0;i <100 ;i++ {

go main2()

}

    time.Sleep(200 * time.Second)

}

func main2() {

  url := "http://localhost:9999/posts"
  method := "GET"

  client := &http.Client {
  }
  req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  res, err := client.Do(req)
  defer res.Body.Close()
  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

  fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

**RESULT ACTUAL**

```
{"id":"123","title":"25115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"23115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"31115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"44115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"105115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"109115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"103115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"115115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"115115","body":""}

{"id":"123","title":"115115","body":""}
```

**RESULT EXPECTED**

```
 {"id":"123","title":"112112","body":""}
 {"id":"123","title":"113113","body":""}
 {"id":"123","title":"115115","body":""}
 {"id":"123","title":"116116","body":""}
 {"id":"123","title":"117117","body":""}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are few ways to do this , a  simple way is to use channels

change the getTitle func to this

```
func getTitle(resultCh chan string)  {
   time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
   resultCh <- "Game Of Thrones"
}
```

and the getPosts will  use it like this

```
func getPosts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

   ch := make(chan string)
   go getTitle(ch)


   s := <-ch // this will wait until getTile inserts data to channel 
   p := Post{
       ID: s,
   }

   json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(p)
}
```

i suspect you are new to go, this is a basic channel usage , check more details here [Channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2)

Comment: Thanks Kojan , I created the channel but result are not in sync. some time I am getting GR4 result in GR1. You can check server and client code. I have updated the question

Comment: The server code looks correct (and the client code is irreverent)

Comment: You can see the result expected versus actual

Comment: if you fire **curl  http://localhost:9999/posts** one by one then it works but when client is used which fires multiple request then it fails

Comment: As @keynan mentions , there are a lot of things going on with your client code, i guess the issue with the code you expect not working because of the i variable. you need to debug this because currently i have no idea whats your question :)

Comment: Hold on, I'll do a proper write up

Comment: Concept wise , GR1 has value of i = 1 it gives value to GR2 as input ( Pass by value ) then GR2 should return 1 and final out put is 11, same if the value of i = 15 then final output is 1515

Comment: thats not correct max, when i was passed to GR2 we had another call to the get function and that did another i++ so when GR2 is finised I is now 2 and not 1 like we passed to it. this is because your i is global

Answer (score 3):

So the problem you're having is that you haven't really leaned how to deal with concurrent code (not a dis, I was there once). Most of this centers not around channels. The channels are working correctly as @kojan's answer explains. Where things go awry is with the `i` variable. Firstly you have to understand that `i` is not being mutated atomically so if your client requests arrive in parallel you can mess up the number:

```
C1 :          C2:
i == 6        i == 6
i++           i++
i == 7        i == 7
```

Two increments in software become one increment in actuality because `i++` is really 3 operations: load, increment, store.

The second problem you have is that `i` is not a pointer, so when you pass `i` to your go routine you're making a copy. the `i` in the go routine is sent back on the channel and becomes the first number in your concatenated string which you can watch increment. However the `i` left behind which is used in the tail of the string has continued to be incremented by successive client invocations.

Comment: Thanks, Instead of variable i, I used newvalue := rand.Intn(100)  ,,go getTitle(ch, newvalue) .. and things are working now